# ObjMap return value or function

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I don't understand why this is not working. I expect $ObjMap to require that the object return the value, or a function that returns that value. See the comment in the code. Anyone know how to make this work?

```js
type TObj = {|
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: boolean,
|};

type Extract = <V>(V) => (() => V) | V

type TType = $ObjMap<TObj, Extract>

function a (): string {
  return 'a';
}

// Expect a to have an error as it is a function that returns a string.
// $ObjMap states that it must be either a number, or a function that returns 
// a number.
const t: TType = {
  a,
  b: 'v',
  c: true,
};
```

https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAKg8gIwFZQLxQN4B8BQUoCGAXFAHYCuAtghAE4A0eUCJAzsLQJakDmj+AYxIIA9iIA2EAqUZYAvgG4cOUJCgBRAB4cCA4GigAeAGoA+ABTGAlGlNRz5m6jvWoWKMeWroMGOGjoACSISACyBGCG8Mj0Gtq0usCmygBm5KR6nCKkhPZWbBzcPJhMtBDA5LQ5AOQE1UpyygLZ7FDAJL7+BhhMxIT8zCTVAG7VA0JttOQQjIpAA

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like a limitation/bug in the implementation. Here's why:

If we change `Extract` such that it would expect the primitives only, we establish a baseline by observing that everything works as expected.

```
type Extract = <V>(V) => V
```

```
19:   a: a,
         ^ Cannot assign object literal to `t` because function [1] is incompatible with number [2] in property `a`. [incompatible-type]
    References:
    11: function a (): string {
        ^ [1]
    2:   a: number,
            ^ [2]
```

Next we modify `Extract` to only accept functions with a return type of number or the respective expected value.

```
type Extract = <V>(V) => ((() => number) | V)
```

Now we observe your expected behavior, error on `a`

```
19:   a: a,
         ^ Cannot assign object literal to `t` because string [1] is incompatible with number [2] in the return value of property `a`. [incompatible-type]
    References:
    11: function a (): string {
                       ^ [1]
    7: type Extract = <V>(V) => ((() => number) | V)
                                        ^ [2]
```

However if we change the accepted type from `number` to `string` the error goes away, which means everything is working fine up to this point.

Finally when we replace `number` with `V` the error disappears. This makes me think the interpreter has trouble resolving and falls back to `any` as a default.

I would expect such problems with static analysis, it is called static for a reason.

*Disclaimer: Everything that I said above are just thoughts and assumptions, I'm posting in an attempt to help, and may be complete garbage, in which case I apologize.*

Comment: I think you are right. I filed a bug in the flow repo.

Comment: @pizzarob my general assumption is, because this happens in vscode's intelliSense - whenever there is an error in typings it falls back to `any`, that this works the same way. Most likely `V` is not what you might think it is in the provided callable type, it is probably not defined. Thus I think it's worth noting that there might be some kind of *special* syntax that will allow you to import `V` into your callable type but I'm not familiar with flow.